# Как собрать новый объект со входящими данными в vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть следующие данные, которые приходят из базы

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 0,
    "phone": "string",
    "first_name": "string",
    "last_name": "string",
    "department": 0
  }
}

{
  "metrics": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "title": "test1",
      "department": 3
    },
{
      "id": 1,
      "title": "test2",
      "department": 3
    }
  ]
}

{
  "facts": [
    {
      "metric_id": 0,
      "fact": 7
    },
{
      "metric_id": 1,
      "fact": 10
    }
  ]
}

{
  "goals": [
    {
      "metric_id": 0,
      "goal": 10
    },
{
      "metric_id": 1,
      "goal": 20
    }
  ]
}
```

Как из этих данных, во vuejs пересобрать такой вот объект

```
const user = {
  id: 0,
  name: "string",
  surname: "string",
  metrics: [
    { id: 0, title: "test1", goals: 10, facts: 7 },
    { id: 1, title: "test2", goals: 20, facts: 10 },
  ],
};
```

Comment: Почему в metrics массиве два объекта с id: 0 и id: 1 почему goals: 10, goals: 20, facts: 7, facts: 10 каким образом эти значения "пересобираются" из исходного объекта? Причем здесь vue.js?